# SQL - select id where id is not in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to select after 4 news the last 12 from a table.
I tried but no results.I got the Undefined $news

```
public function get_all_news_home()
{
    $news = array();
    # ne conectam la baza de date
    $this->load->database();
    # selectam stirile de top
    $last_news_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready='Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4");
    $last_news = $this->db->query($last_news_query);
    $last_news = ($last_news->num_rows()) ? $last_news->result_array() : NULL;
    foreach ($last_news as $ln) 
    {
        array_push($news,array('id' => $ln['ID']));
    }

    $all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.Ready = 'Y' AND News.ID NOT IN ('$news') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 12");

    if($all_news->num_rows())
    {
        $all_news = $all_news->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        $all_news = NULL;
    }
    return $all_news;
}
```

Help me please.How can I exclude the first 4 id

Comment: You missing semi-colon on first line in `$news = array();`.

Comment: And from where you getting `$news` variable in the function `get_all_news_home` ?

Comment: Also you can directly use LIMIT clause to skip first 4 news from the table.

Comment: $news not defined in model function.Pass these to the function

Comment: I edited the code..How with the limit

Comment: You must add fetch after queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 ...
$newsIds = implode(',', array_values($news));
 ...    
$all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.ID NOT IN ('$newsIds') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 12");
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the limit clause

...

```
$last_news_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE Type = 1 AND Ready='Y' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 0,4");
```

...

```
$all_news = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM News WHERE News.Ready = 'Y' AND News.ID NOT IN ('$news') ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 4,12");
```

...